# How to accessing a viewbag in typescript file?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I am using typescript. I want to access the viewbag details in typescript file in asp.net core project. How to access it in typescript?

I am getting viewbag data from the controller. I want to access that in typescript file.

I am new to typescript. So can anyone help me.

Comment: You can't (directly), since the ViewBag is server-side, and TypeScript runs on the client. A workaround might be to serialize the ViewBag to JSON and insert it in a Javascript variable on your page.

Comment: I didn't use the javascript...I only use the typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `viewbag` value as the following code.

HTML

```
<input type = "text" hidden = "hidden" id = viewbagid value="@viewbagname">
```

SCRIPT

```
function Test()
{
   var viewbagval = $("#viewbagid").val();
}
```